# Performance issue when reading Blog mysql database with SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Restful SpringBoot project using Mysql Database LONGBLOB to store file. With large file, it take very long time to response file data to front end FE via Restful API.

My Entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_DEVICE_DATA")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyDeviceData {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "FILE")
    private byte[] file;

    @Column(name = "DEVICE_NAME")
    private String deviceName;


    @Column(name = "DEVICE_CODE")
    private String deviceCode;

    @Column(name= "FILE_NAME")
    private String fileName;
}
```

In databse, I using LongBlob

[image]

How to improve performance when read My SQL Blog using Spring JPA

Comment: Well all the data needs to be read (the field isn't lazy). So if you don't need the field to display on the front-end then don't retrieve it. Retrieve only the data you need.

Comment: How big is the blob?  How many rows in the table?  What SQL is it running?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using `java.sql.Blob`

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "FILE")
private Blob file;
```